# Skin (histology)

Tags: cell-biology, skin, histology

[image: This is a skin sample stained with Masson's trichrome stain.]

Our instructor share this image with us. She didn't specify much. She only said it was a skin sample.
Could you tell me what is the thing that was pointed at with the blue arrow?

I believe that I found a similar image in Ross' Histology (e6) Plate 44.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add, what you think this is? And what are the pros and cons of your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to say based on the limited informations about the sample, but I could assume that this is a [Masson's Trichrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masson%27s_trichrome_stain) staining. Briefly: blue/green - collagen, red/pink - cytoplasm, dark pink/brown - nucleus.

Presence of the adipose tissue (white area on the right) and a lot of collagen (green) suggest that the sample highly likely comes from dermis. The large structure pointed by the arrow looks like an [eccrine sweat gland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccrine_sweat_gland). Here, you can see it in classical haematoxylin and eosin staining:

[image]

Alternatively, see: http://medcell.med.yale.edu/histology/skin_lab/eccrine_sweat_glands.php